# Ajax get div from the return object of If statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an if statement that returns an html as data object.
What I would like to do is to get specific div from the return data and display it within a div.
I am trying to do this with the following code but without success...

My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8888/drupal",
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'text',
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#chat_list_out").html($(data).filter('#sidebar-first'));
    }
});
```

Comment: I've run into problems with more-recent versions of jQuery when trying to $(data) some server-generated HTML. It seems like extra whitespace in the HTML causes it not to parse well. What error message are you getting?

Comment: `$('data')` should be okey if it is a well formed xml tree like `<div id="sidebar-first"><span>okey</span></div>` but not `<div id="foo"></div><div id="bar">test</div>`

Comment: @bcholmes is correct, you may need to `$.trim` the response if it starts with whitespace.

Comment: I have no error but nothing is print to the #chat_list_out.

Comment: What does show `alert(data)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use the load function which allows you to just grab a specific div

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("#chat_list_out").load('http://localhost:8888/drupal #sidebar-first');
```